# Locking specific cells and creating a summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook I'm trying to create a vba code for but I keep running into different errors...runtimee error, object error etc

I have created a series of forms and I need to lock the cells that contain specific texts. The forms ask a series of questions, including First name, Last name and Degree. I need to lock the cells containing these texts but leave those that will contain the responses open.

Also, I need the responses for the cells containing Degrees and location to feed a summary sheet.

The closest I got was using an If function but it didn't quite cover everything I wanted to do. Please help if you can.

Comment: Hi Jen, we *probably* can help, however the problem description is a little bit too vague for us to have any idea what the specific problem is, assuming you want to narrow this down to one particular issue. Can you [edit] your question to include the relevant code where the error is occurring, along with the actual specific error message you're getting?

Comment: *"I have a workbook I'm trying to create a vba code for but I keep running into different errors...runtimee error, object error etc"* - please show us the code so we can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using User Forms to collect the data then you are likely using VBA to transfer the user form data to te worksheet. If the worksheet is protected with the UserInterfaceOnly:=true argument, you can do anything you want with the worksheet's data (e.g. add/revise/delete/etc) through VBA and the user cannot make any modifications.

Run this once.

```
sub allowVBA()

    with thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet1")
        .unprotect password:="password"
        .protect password:="password", userinterfaceonly:=true
    end with

end sub
```